# Struggling to understand observer patterns

Tags: observer-pattern

I've read as much as I can about observer patterns but I am failing to fully understand what/when it would be used. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it like a publisher / subscriber model.

An example would be stocks

When the price of a stock object (subject) is updated, any "investor" (observer) that is subscribed to this stock is notified of the updated price

Answer (score 0):

Observer is used in situations where you want disparate components of the code to be notified when something changes.  Event based systems come to mind. Typically in event based systems, when you register the handler, whatever framework you use will use an observer implementation to notify the handlers when the event fires.

One area I have seen it used is in the Sproutcore framework.  The framework has a feature called 'key-value observing'.  Basically, you can set up observers on a field of an object, and when that field value changes, the observers fire automatically.  This is advantageous because, for example, if a view element has an observer on a parent view's layout, when things get resized the view can redraw itself.  Or, lets say a value changes and you need to recalculate some other values, you set up an observer on the initial value and then from your observer you can do the recalculation.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: So similar to an event listener?

Comment: @nathan, correct.  Typically in event based systems, when you register the handler, whatever framework you use will use an observer implementation to notify the handlers when the event fires.

Answer (score 0):

> [Observer pattern](http://elope.wordpress.com/2006/04/07/tutorial-on-observer-pattern-2/) is used when An
>   object needs to notify other object(s)
>   if it changes. . So observer pattern
>   has
>
> 1) Subject or Source : on which any
>   action will happen.
>
> 2) One or more Observers : Whom Source
>   needs to notify if any change has
>   taken place .

Here is nice article on this:

- [Speaking on the Observer pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2001-05/04-qa-0525-observer.html)

Answer (score 0):

I guess an example will make it clear: Let's say you are receiving data from a socket and want to be notified whenever some data arrives. So you register a observer with the class that is receiving the data. Once the data comes, a particular method of your observer will be called in which you can appropriate action to process the data.

Answer (score 0):

The observer pattern is used when many observers need to know about state changes in some object. It can be used for instance in a GUI where you want several components to change "automatically" when some other component changes.

So let's say you have a check box and depending on the state (checked or unchecked) you want other components to be visible or not. The number of other components may be variable. So you want them all the register themselves with the checkbox. The checkbox then notifies each observer that a change has occurred when the user clicks and they can decide how to react to that change. So the logic of how they react resides in the observers. The checkbox does not need to know what they do.